# Trying to use dll from python

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am running:

```sh
>> setup.py --build_ext
```

inplace for the following `setup.py`:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

ext_modules = [
    Extension('ImgProc',
              ['ImgProc.pyx'],
              language="c++",  
              libraries=['ImgProc'],
              library_dirs=['.'])
    ]

setup(
    name = 'ImgProc',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    include_dirs=[np.get_include()]
)
```

I get the error that `build_ext` is not recognized.
I am pretty new in python so I suppose I am missing an install package or something because it was working on my other PC.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on another PC, then my initial guess is that `Cython` is not installed on your default python interpreter. So on your other PC if the default interpreter version is `python 2.X` and `Cython` is installed it will run. On your other PC, figure out what your default python version is:

```sh
# python 2.X
$ python --version
Python 2.7.16

# python 3.X
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

To list the packages in each interpreter run [pip list](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/). Here is an example output:

```sh
$ pip list
docutils (0.10)
Jinja2 (2.7.2)
MarkupSafe (0.18)
Pygments (1.6)
Sphinx (1.2.1)
...
```

[Cython installation](https://pypi.org/project/Cython/) should run like this if it is not installed:

```sh
# python 2.X
$ pip install Cython

# python 3.X
$ pip3 install Cython
```